# Dollar sign forced left or right

Tags: regex

I'm learning regular expressions and testing my expressions on [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com). So far this regular expression matches any number less than 1000:

> ^\d{1,3}$

For example: 999 gets matched.

I'm being asked to match the expression only if a $ sign is placed left or right. I have no idea how to do this. So I thought:

A dollar sign on the right can be detected by doing this. For example 999$ gets matched:

> ^\d{1,3}**\$**$

A dollar sign on the left can be detected by doing this. For example $999 gets matched:

> ^**\$**\d{1,3}$

I thought, using the operator **?**, I can accept the $ sign on left and on right:

> ^**(\$)?**\d{1,3}**(\$)?**$

This solves partially the problem, the regular expression now matches:

- 999$
- $999

But also matches:

- $999$
- 999

How can I fix my regular expression forcing at least a dollar sign right or left (but not both) and rejecting a number with no $ (we can't use character count 9 and 99 and 999 are all matched)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the ways you can do is using pipe `|` (alternative operator):

```
^(\$\d{1,3}|\d{1,3}\$)$
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aD2rI1/27)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the way you first assumed, making the dollar sign optional
at both ends, but add an assertion requiring at most one dollar sign.
The rest falls into place.

`^(?=[^$]*\$[^$]*$)\$?(?:\d|[1-9]\d|[1-9]\d{2})\$?$`

```
 ^ 
 (?= [^$]* \$ [^$]* $ )
 \$? 
 (?:
      \d 
   |  [1-9] \d 
   |  [1-9] \d{2} 
 )
 \$?
 $
```

or, its unusual to allow leading zero's on dollar amounts, but if you want to
do that, its ..

`^(?=[^$]*\$[^$]*$)\$?\d{1,3}\$?$`

shorter, but allows leading zero's.

```
 ^ 
 (?= [^$]* \$ [^$]* $ )
 \$? \d{1,3} \$?
 $
```